# JavaScript interdependent functions

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have this in my HTML file:

```
<script src="/file.js"/>
<script>
func_from_file();
main_func(){
    alert("some alert");
}
</script>
```

And this in my file.js:

```
func_from_file(){
    alert("some alert from file");
}
main_func();
```

So I have this script in HTML file that calls the function from `file.js`, and also have a script inside `file.js` that calls function from html file. How to avoid `reference error`?

P.S. I can't splice the scripts, can't put script from HTML page inside some `file.js`, and I can't change loading queue. Help me please.

EDIT:

I will try to correct my question.

HTML page:

```
<head>
<script src="/file.js"/>
<script>
func_from_file();
start(){
    main_func(){
        alert("some alert");
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="start()"/>
</body>
```

And file.js:

```
func_from_file(){
    alert("some alert from file");
}
main_func();
```

NOW it's true code. I have forgot half of it.

Comment: what is the exact folder structure? where is this `file.js` located in relation to `file.html`?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't add 'main_func()' to file.js though, seems pretty inefficiënt to do so

Comment: Circular dependencies are a problem, yes. Stop creating circular dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is not that the functions are wrong, but that you're declaring your script tags wrong, try this:

**HTML:**

```
<script src="folder/structure/here/file.js"></script>
<script>
func_from_file();
main_func(){
    alert("some alert");
}
</script>
```

**JS:**

```
func_from_file(){
    alert("some alert from file");
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    main_func();
});
```

**EDIT:**
This is what I got now, I think this is what you want?

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="file.js"></script>
    <script>
    func_from_file();
        function main_func(){
            alert("some alert");
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button onclick="main_func()"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
function func_from_file(){
    alert("some alert from file");
}
main_func();
```

or if you want to load the page before showing `main_func()`

```
function func_from_file(){
    alert("some alert from file");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    main_func();
});
```

Comment: I have forget to say that I'm calling main_func() not at pageload (or ready) BUT at button onclick.

Comment: @elpax then forget about the `$(document).ready` also, are you sure to your `file.js` is linked correctly?

Comment: I'm sure. I need to call function in HTML page from JS file but only after HTML pag call to js file.

Comment: @elpax — You are wrong (or the code in your question has errors that your real code doesn't have and you need to provide a real [MCVE])

Comment: if you could make a code snippet and add it you your question, that would be nice to have

Comment: just did, check my answer

Comment: is this what you were looking for? if so, would you concider accepting this as the correct answer so that other people can find it and learn from it? if it's not, please elaborate.

Answer (score -1):

You can put the call of main_func() in file.js inside window.onload = function() {}

This way it will call once whole page gets loaded

or put the main_func() call in file.js inside setTimeout function of javascript and put the timeout according to your convenience.